# Как настроить SSH тунель Vagrant-e используя существующий приватный ключ RSA?

Tags: vagrant

Пробовал копировать ключи

```
config.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa.pub", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"   
config.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

И подымать тунель:

```
ssh -f username@example.com -L 33306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```